# Resizing div to its container?

Tags: html, css

I have a square block of `100*100px`, there is a container block that may be resized. I want to resize the inner block so it always be inside the parent without overflow and always square (to be resized dynamically)

**Note:** I want to maintain the square shape of the inner `div`

```css
#child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
#par {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="par">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean without the child overflowing, or without using the property `overflow`?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I want the inner div to be dynamically resized according to the parent's dimensions. that mean that when its border touches the inner div, the inner div starts to response to the new dimensions.

Comment: That sounds too simple, all you have to do is use percentage units for the child -> see example: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/mheoqbnw/

Comment: Can you provide an image _painting_ an example of the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an element to be a square (ratio of 1:1) then just add `padding-bottom: 100%` to it. If you want that square to have content then the inner content of that square must be `absolutely` positioned.

```css
body { width: 200px; }

.square {
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* 1:1 aspect ratio (square) */
  border:1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

You can place the square in a container/parent but you did not say how overflowing should behave?

```css
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.square {
  padding-bottom: 100%; /* 1:1 aspect ratio (square) */
  border:1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.square .inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child square">
    <div class="inner">responsive square 1:1</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: css square ratio preview]

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/mheoqbnw/

Answer (score 2):

what you want is this:
http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/
element-queries, the future

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#par{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border:2px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#par #child{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 25%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/voj2wsyb/

Comment: it doesn't maintain the square shape :(

Answer (score 0):

Just give the `#child` element a `max-height` and `max-width` of 100%:

```
#child{
  height:100px;
  max-height:100%;
  width:100px;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the child min, max and height  100% it's going to look to it's parent and with 100 % it's taking the same height

Answer (score 0):

Here you are :-

```css
.child
{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:red;}
.par
{
    position: relative;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:2px solid black;
} 
.par:before{
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
.par > .child{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
<div class="par">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If it helps, mark the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I use EQCSS, an element queries plugin that lets me grab values from JavaScript to use in my CSS. Here's a demo with a column 33% wide that has a square that will resize responsively inside it:

```
<section>
  <div></div>
</section>
<style>
  section {width: 33%;}
  @element 'div' {
    $this {
      width: auto;
      height: eval("clientWidth")px;
      background: red;
    }
  }
</style>
<script src=http://elementqueries.com/EQCSS.js></script>
```

In this snippet, the `width: auto` means it expands to fill its container. The `eval('clientWidth')` is inside of the element query, so it refers to `this.clientWidth` where the `this` is the element that matches the query. This means the height of our square will always be equal to its width! (a square).

Check it out: http://elementqueries.com

I also use this same technique to allow me to resize Youtube and Vimeo iframes according to their aspect ratio without needing a wrapper:

```
@element 'iframe' {
  $this {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: eval("scrollWidth/(width/height)")px;
  }
}
```

Responsive video scaling demo: http://elementqueries.com/demos/video-scaling.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### There is now the CSS attribute `aspect-ratio`:

```css
body { width: 200px; }

.square {
    border: 1px solid red;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    width: 100px; /* <-- optional, this is only for the demo */
}

.not-a-square {
    border: 1px solid green;
    aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
    width: 100px; /* <-- optional, this is only for the demo */
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="not-a-square"></div>
```

Support: https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_img_aspect_ratio_computed_from_attributes